# using insertAfter a class name

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

how can i use **insertAfter** a class when the class is not unique? Is there a way? lets say I wanna move div "name"after div class "desc" or maybe to another place?

After a While it goes into some type of loop and I am prompted to Stop the script

http://jsfiddle.net/rudyten/ffGZk/

```
$(".image").insertAfter(".name");
$(".desc").insertAfter(".image");


<div class='box'>
    <div class='name'>NAME</div>
    <div class='image'>IMAGE</div>
    <div class='desc'>DESC</div>
</div>
<div class='box'>
    <div class='name'>NAME</div>
    <div class='image'>IMAGE</div>
    <div class='desc'>DESC</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `insertAfter` in a `each` function like below:

```
$('.container').each(function(){
    if (loc == "AB") {
        $(this).find(".image").insertAfter($(this).find(".name"));
        $(this).find(".desc").insertAfter($(this).find(".image"));
    }

    if (loc == "BA") {
        $(this).find(".image").insertAfter($(this).find(".desc"));
        $(this).find(".name").insertAfter($(this).find(".image"));
    }

    if (loc == "AA") {
        $(this).find(".desc").insertAfter($(this).find(".name"));
        $(this).find(".image").insertAfter($(this).find(".desc"));
    }

    if (loc == "BB") {
        $(this).find(".name").insertAfter($(this).find(".image"));
        $(this).find(".desc").insertAfter($(this).find(".name"));
    }
});
```

Here is jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/ffGZk/4/